# Randomise an Android marker colour

Tags: java, android

i know how to change a marker colour but is it possible to randomise one with BitmapDecriptorFactory with a random generator of some sort e.g.

```
            final String [] colours = new String[]{
                    "HUE_AZURE",
                    "HUE_BLUE",
                    "HUE_CYAN",
                    "HUE_GREEN",
                    "HUE_MAGENTA",
                    "HUE_ORANGE",
                    "HUE_RED",
                    "HUE_ROSE",
                    "HUE_VIOLET",
                    "HUE_YELLOW"
            };
            final Random r=new Random();

 LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude);
            Marker perth = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(PERTH)
                    .draggable(true)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.(r.colours))));
```

something along those lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for `BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#defaultMarker(float)):

> `public static BitmapDescriptor defaultMarker (float hue)`
>
> Creates a bitmap descriptor that refers to a colorization of the
>   default marker image. For convenience, there is a predefined set of
>   hue values. See example `HUE_YELLOW`.
>
> **Parameters** `hue`  The hue of the marker. Value must be greater or equal
>   to 0 and less than 360.

In particular, take note of the last sentence: *"Value must be greater or equal
to 0 and less than 360."*

That means that picking a random colour could be as easy as:

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(new Random().nextInt(360));
```

If you wanted to select a random colour from a predefined set of colours, you could go with something close to what you already have:

```
float[] colours = { BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE /* etc */ };
BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(colours[new Random().nextInt(colours.length)]);
```

Comment: Yes i read the documentation and discovered it was a float, the random int worked no problem thank you @MH.